# Reconocimiento de vocales

Tags: java, caracteres

sucede que tengo este código que es para reconocer vocales en una frase y contarlas, el problema es cuando se ingresa una vocal con tilde, no sé porqué no se valida y no se cuenta como vocal, solo reconoce las que están sin tilde. Cabe resaltar que el código debe quedar tal cual está, sin usar chatAt o alguna otra función. Alguien que porfa me ayude.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class sin_titulo {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String frase;
    String vocales = "aeiouáéíóúü";
    int cantVocales = 0;

    //El usuario ingresa una frase, vamos a contar cuántas vocales tiene
    System.out.print("Ingrese una frase: ");
    frase = br.readLine();

    //Pasamos toda la frase a minusculas para no tener que preguntar 2 veces por cada vocal
    frase = frase.toLowerCase();

    //Lista de vocales que vamos a buscar definida arriba al igual que la variable cantVocales igualada a cero
    //Comparar todas las letras de frase con las de vocales y encontrar coincidencias
    for (int i = 1; i <= frase.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= vocales.length(); j++) {
            if (frase.substring(i-1, i).equals(vocales.substring(j-1, j))) {
                cantVocales += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La frase contiene " + cantVocales + " vocales.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias agregar un ejemplo de frase que no te reconoce y cuantas vocales cuenta en esos casos?

Comment: Hola a mi si me reconoce las tildes en las palabras con tu código, puede ser que System.in tome como referencia el idioma que tengas del teclado, InputStreamReader ademas del System.in deja especificar un charset, intenta agregando UTF-8, no lo puedo probar porque ya de por si me funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale, encontré la solución, las propiedades del proyecto, a pesar de tener el encoding en UTF-8, había que poner ISO-8859-1 que según leí, es como el equivalente a ASCII. Aquí dejo una imagen (Clic derecho en el proyecto y luego propiedades):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien cuando tenga el mismo problema, me causó curiosidad la respuesta de JFrame que me dijo que a él le había funcionado, busqué un compilador online de Java y funcionaba, así que entendí que era alguna propiedad que tenía mal configurada. Y bueno, nuevamente, espero que a alguien le sirva en algún momento